# Pause a script till a certain time and start again at another certain time

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I made a RGB LED color changing script on my raspberry pi 3 for my setup but i want it to make it so at 11PM the lights stop and start again at 9AM. How can i make this possible ?
Thank you,
PhantomX

Comment: Hi. From a quick google I see that raspberry has a crontab. I guess it would be much easier to setup with cron than to do it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `time` library in python, there is a `time.localtime()` function that will return the current time as a structure.

You can check for the hour to be 23 (11PM), then turn the lights off, then have it sleep for 36000 seconds (10 hours) and then turn the lights back on.

Alternatively, check for the hour to be 9 (9AM) every few minutes, and turn the lights on in the event that the script may restart during the night

Example:

```
import time

while True:
    if time.localtime().tm_hour == 23:
        lights_off()
        time.sleep(3600) # No need to check for at least 1 hour
    elif time.localtime().tm_hour == 9:
        lights_on()
        time.sleep(3600)
    time.sleep(60) # Checks every  minute
```

Time Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.localtime

Comment: When it comes to checking time, there are a lot of failure cases that can occur if you expect the time to be exactly a certain value at the time you poll it. It's much safer to check if it falls within X and Y boundaries and perform actions based on the current value.

Comment: @Johnny in this scenario it is looking for an hour value, there should not be too much error checking every minute or two for a 60 minute window.

Comment: Agreed, but still bad practice.

Comment: @Johnny out of curiosity, and for better practice in the future, which bounds would be applicable in a scenario like the one here?

Comment: A pi controls the lights on my aquarium. There is a power outage between 10:30pm and 11:30pm. I missed the "off" poll at 11pm, so they turn back on until I poll again at 9am, at which time they've been on 10 hours more than supposed to. At 9am, the trigger says 'turn the lights on,' again(!), so now the lights *remain* on for an additional 12 hours. This will result in sunburn, bleaching, and coral death. So while true, i poll every X seconds to see if the time is between 9am and 11pm: if so, lights_on(). If the time is between 11pm and 9am, lights_off(). Simple problem, safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more idempotent solution that guarantees the lights are in the correct state regardless of what time you start the script or if it gets interrupted.

```
from datetime import time, datetime
from time import sleep

morning = time(9,0,0)
evening = time(23,0,0)

while True:

    while morning < datetime.now().time() < evening:
        print 'lights on...'
        sleep(1)

    print 'lights off...'
    sleep(1)
```